# Global data behaviour in Multi-thread environment, C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an application running three threads. All three threads are doing some operations based on the status of a global variable. 2 of the threads are running the same piece of code and 1 thread is running another piece of code.

Ex:

Initial value of global variable is false

```
gGlobalVarLock = false;

thread 1:
while(true == gGlobalVarLock)
{
  /*wait for flag to become false*/
}
/*after the flag becomes false*/    
{
  mutex.lock();
  gGlobalVarLock = true;

  /*run some code*/

  gGlobalVarLock = false;
  mutex.unlock();
}

thread 2 and 3,    
while(true == gGlobalVarLock)
{
  /*wait for flag to become false*/
}
/*after the flag becomes false*/
{
  mutex.lock();
  gGlobalVarLock = true;

  /*run some other code*/

  gGlobalVarLock = false;
  mutex.unlock();
}
```

Now, after the application starts due to the init false value of gGlobalVarLock, one of the threads starts execution, and should lock the other threads from executing. As per my understanding the above implementation is somehow ensuring that the  gGlobalVarLock is locked by the execution thread, and no other thread is getting access to it once the code under the mutex.lock() for any particular thread is executing. It looks like it is also locking the global variable under the lock. But I don't know how.

My code seems to be running fine. But I have one doubt. Mutex will lock the code for thread 2 and 3 since these two threads use the same piece of code for execution. But for the thread 1 which is running some other piece of code, how does the locking work? Does the mutex.lock() in that thread ensure that th gGlobalVarLock is locked for other threads when it is executing the code under its mutex.lock(). Does that mutex ensure the gGlobalVarLock is not changed my the other threads which are running some other piece of code? My understanding is mutex.lock() locks common code used by different threads. Then how is the global variable getting locked in my case where different threads are running different codes.

Does mutex.lock() lock global variables in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: you never shown/told the type of `mutex` by the way.

Comment: its a global mutex in my application having these threads

Answer (score 1):

The point is precisely that if you create a mutex object in the parent process and share it between several threads, this object's memory is shared by the threads (those are not processes)

Should you create processes instead (using `fork()`) the memory would be copied and it would not work.

But between threads, memory is shared so the object is shared. You have a single instance of `mutex` in memory for all your threads.

This object will ensure that only one thread at a time is accessing the critical section located between the calls of `lock` and `unlock`.

In a nutshell, your code is OK.

Comment: do you mean it is the shared resources/memory between only which get locked by a mutex?

Comment: no, memory is shared by the threads (or you would not be able to access your boolean/see its value changing). It's just that mutex objects are protected by an exclusion mechanism at the os level.

Comment: so mutex protects memory alone, nothing else?

Comment: mutex ensure that no other thread is executing their critical section when the current thread has entered its own critical section. That concerns memory, files, all shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

The mutex assures that after the `lock()` just the thread that acquires the mutex can execute the code until reach the `unlock()` call. Unless you have a code very slow, you can think it's being executing simultaneously. However the block of code between the `lock()` and `unlock()` is going to executed by just one thread each time.

Answer (score 0):

A mutex does not lock variables, it only locks itself. By restricting access to a variable behind a mutex you can *protect* that variable, but if the variable is global, there is no guarantee that elsewhere in your code you might unintentionally access it without going through the mutex.

For example, in your code, nobody uses the mutex until they have already accessed the, global variable and found it to be false. So it is entirely possible that all three threads would contend for the mutex lock.

In your example, the global variable seems redundant, you seem to be using it as a filter to protect access to the mutex.

You may be looking for something called a condition variable to use in conjunction with your mutex.